# Disallow Jenkins build on submits from a specific Perforce user

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, perforce, build-automation

I have written a script that will auto-update version files for libraries that we are working on. Currently, we are using the [P4 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/P4+Plugin).

When Jenkins picks up on a change to the directory (using polling), a build is triggered. As part of that build, Jenkins uses the Perforce command line client, to check out, and update using the script, the version file to match the Perforce submit number.

This all works fine, the issue is, when the version file is updated, the next time a poll happens, it triggers a build since the version file changed. Which leads to an infinite loop of triggering build to update the version file.

My question is, is there a way to tell Jenkins not to build if the change came from a certain Perforce user? I've found the [Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) seems to have pretty flexible rules about who/what can trigger builds, and I was wondering if there was a way to do this in Jenkins without relying on an external plugin, or a non-git plugin, since my I am working with Perforce.

Or possibly even being able to tell Jenkins not to trigger a build if only certain files have changed could work as well.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can approach this?

Edit:
The version will change each time someone makes a submit to the main codeline of a project. This is done so we can track an internal library version and keep it synced with the Perforce submit that made it. That way we have a way to track which Perforce commit made the update, and it can be tracked in Jira as well.

Right now, the script is just a dumb c# command line exe. I was hoping to avoid having to hook it up to the [P4API.NET](https://www.perforce.com/blog/110909/p4apinet-perforce-net-platform) and write all that logic myself.

Comment: The script to update the versions files is part of the build? Why? How often do versions change? Can you alter the script to NOT touch the version files if nothing changes?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Have you tried the Polling Build Filter of "Exclude changes from user"?

Comment: @tkosinski where do you see that option? I didn't see that option in the P4 Plugin

Comment: @tkosinski Wow, I'm not sure how I missed that option before. I suppose I was trying to avoid doing this with polling, and I glossed right over it. If you want to add that as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Polling Build Filter of "Exclude changes from user"

[image]